# Before Trigger & Formula Field Reliability

Tags: apex, trigger, formula-field, before-trigger, recursion

I have the following code in a before-insert/update trigger:

```
for(Contact c : newCs) { // newCs is Trigger.new
    // Various "inside the main Contact-trigger-for-loop" actions go here
    //...
    if (c.Coll__c != null) {
        if (
            // Don't bother if nothing of that could feed into an OwnerId change has changed.
            isInsert ||
            (
                isUpdate &&
                (
                    c.Coll__c != oldCsMap.get(c.Id).Coll__c ||
                    (c.Coll__c == 'Four Year College' && c.Formula_4Yr_Couns_Sugg_SFID__c != null && c.Formula_4Yr_Couns_Sugg_SFID__c != oldCsMap.get(c.Id).Formula_4Yr_Couns_Sugg_SFID__c) ||
                    (c.Coll__c == 'Two Year College' && c.Formula_2Yr_Couns_Sugg_SFID__c != null && c.Formula_2Yr_Couns_Sugg_SFID__c != oldCsMap.get(c.Id).Formula_2Yr_Couns_Sugg_SFID__c)
                )
            )
        ) {
            // Move Formula_2Yr_Couns_Sugg_SFID__c/Formula_4Yr_Couns_Sugg_SFID__c to OwnerId as appropriate for Coll__c (OK to do at any time in execution context -- do NOT recursion-proof)
            if (c.Coll__c == 'Four Year College' && c.Formula_4Yr_Couns_Sugg_SFID__c != null && c.OwnerId != c.Formula_4Yr_Couns_Sugg_SFID__c) {
                    c.OwnerId = c.Formula_4Yr_Couns_Sugg_SFID__c;
            } else if (c.Coll__c == 'Two Year College' && c.Formula_2Yr_Couns_Sugg_SFID__c != null && c.OwnerId != c.Formula_2Yr_Couns_Sugg_SFID__c) {
                    c.OwnerId = c.Formula_2Yr_Couns_Sugg_SFID__c;
            }
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

Basically, there are 3 fields (1 normal, 2 formula) where, if any of them have changed, I want to copy the value of the appropriate formula field into OwnerId (the "normal" field is used to decide which "formula" field is appropriate).

Since this is an inside-the-same-object simple field-value-copy, a "BEFORE" trigger context is very tempting because it'd be so efficient.  I was told that people want this to be slipped into an existing trigger handler specifically because they could not manage to fit even one more "Process Builder" onto Contact (big loads are already going "flump" with respect to CPU time).

However, since the value to be copied (and the "should I proceed?" decision) involves formula fields, I can't tell if it's going to do an *accurate* job.

My gut tells me that, particularly since it's not recursion-proofed *(upon request)*, it'll be pretty darned good for situations where a real live data-load / user-hitting-"save" change one of the 3 values *(the formula field's value would be changed by changing where the prospective student lives, where they go to school, by changing the value of `Coll__c`, etc.)* because there are so many Processes & Workflows on Contact that *some* pass across this code should probably pick up on enough to get the right value into OwnerId.

And my quick-and-dirty unit test passes:

```
private static testMethod void testAssignedCounselorCopyToOwner() {

    Id counsProfileId= [select id, name from profile where name='Counselor'][0].Id;
    User testUser = new User(alias = 'u1', email='example123@example.com', emailencodingkey='UTF-8', lastname='Test', languagelocalekey='en_US', localesidkey='en_US', profileid = counsProfileId, timezonesidkey='America/Los Angeles', username='example123@example.com');
    INSERT testUser;

    ContactTriggerHandler.skipAssignedCounselorCopyToOwner = TRUE;
    Contact c1 = new Contact(LastName='c1Last', Coll__c='Two Year College');
    System.runAs(testUser) { INSERT new List<Contact>{c1}; {} }
    ContactTriggerHandler.skipAssignedCounselorCopyToOwner = FALSE;

    Id c1OwnerIdBeforeTest = [SELECT OwnerId FROM Contact WHERE Id = :c1.Id][0].OwnerId;
    System.assertEquals(testUser.Id, c1OwnerIdBeforeTest); // Make sure "OwnerId" is simply the "test user" who INSERT-ed c1

    Test.startTest();
    c1.Coll__c='Four Year College';
    Contact c2 = new Contact(LastName='c2Last', Coll__c='Two Year College');
    System.runAs(testUser) {
        UPDATE new List<Contact>{c1}; {}
        INSERT new List<Contact>{c2}; {}
    }
    Test.stopTest();

    System.assertNotEquals(c1OwnerIdBeforeTest,[SELECT OwnerId FROM Contact WHERE Id = :c1.Id][0].OwnerId); // Make sure the c1 owner was changed from the "test user" upon UPDATE
    System.assertNotEquals(testUser.Id,[SELECT OwnerId FROM Contact WHERE Id = :c2.Id][0].OwnerId);  // Make sure the c2 owner was set to something besides the "test user" upon INSERT
    System.assertNotEquals([SELECT OwnerId FROM Contact WHERE Id = :c1.Id][0].OwnerId,[SELECT OwnerId FROM Contact WHERE Id = :c2.Id][0].OwnerId); // Note that this presumes two-year & four-year counselors for low-info recruits don't overlap.  May need to remove this test if such presumptions become untrue due to staff assignment changes.  It's a quick-and-dirty way to examine #2 for having a "2-year" counselor rather than knowing exactly who that should be ("not the 4-year counselor" is the test).

}
```

I also threw a couple of `System.assert(FALSE,...)`s into my code at various points -- the `Formula_4Yr_Couns_Sugg_SFID__c` & `Formula_2Yr_Couns_Sugg_SFID__c` values inside the loop, before my big "if," have the same values for "c1" as they do when SOQL-queried after "c1" has finished INSERT-ing in the test class -- they're not *blank* inside the loop or anything as the INSERT first gets BEFORE-processed.  Similarly, c1's `Formula_2Yr_Couns_Sugg_SFID__c` goes NULL in both places (inside the BEFORE handler loop *and* after the UPDATE is done) as it's UPDATE'd -- without it mattering whether I suppressed trigger-post-processing on C1's initial INSERT.  So things *look promising* with respect to the data integrity of formula-field values in BEFORE loops.

Still, I have my doubts.  A nagging part of my brain suspects that whatever values of `Formula_4Yr_Couns_Sugg_SFID__c` & `Formula_2Yr_Couns_Sugg_SFID__c` exist on "c" in a "Trigger.new" loop may not be what I think they are (perhaps old values from previous recursions, perhaps not-actually-yet-recalculated, etc).

Does anyone know details about typical values found in `(Trigger.new)[#].Formula_Field__c` references?

*(I'd love it if somehow, my existing code could be sufficient, since it's meant to be fired upon **every** Contact Update/Insert, and anything more "foolproof" seems like it would involve at least 1 SOQL query.)*

Comment: So to be clear, none of the formulas reference anything cross-object? If so you should be good. Even if you couldn't reference directly, I think `recalculateFormulas()` would work.

Comment: No, no cross-object references.   Thanks!  If you want to make this an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If none of the formulas reference anything cross-object, you should be good.

If you have any trouble referencing it directly, you can call `recalculateFormulas()` to ensure you have the correct value.

Comment: recalculateFormulas() will error in a lot of cases, i.e. if record includes relationships or non-updateable fields, see https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008bvw

Answer (score 7):

As an addendum to @adrianLarson comment:

Cross-object formula fields may be available in the **before trigger** context if the parent relationship is based on a required field or on a lookup field with non-null value.  Looking at the [Trigger Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm?search_text=trigger%20context)

> 1 On the server, Salesforce: Loads the original record from the database
> or initializes the record for an upsert statement.
>
> 2 Loads the new
> record field values from the request and overwrites the old values. If
> the request came from a standard UI edit page, Salesforce runs system
> validation to check the record for:
>
> ...Compliance with layout-specific
> rules
>
> ...**Required values** at the layout level and **field-definition level**
>
> ...Valid field formats
>
> ...Maximum field length
>
> When the request comes from
> other sources, such as an Apex application or a SOAP API call,
> Salesforce **validates only the foreign keys**. Prior to executing a
> trigger, Salesforce verifies that any custom foreign keys do not refer
> to the object itself. Salesforce runs user-defined validation rules if
> multiline items were created, such as quote line items and opportunity
> line items.
>
> **3. Executes all before triggers**.
>
> 4 Runs most system validation steps again, such as verifying that all required fields have a non-null value

So, let's consider some examples:

---

Example 1 - `OpportunityLineItem` - cross object formula field to `Opportunity.xxx`

OLIs inserted from the standard UI must, by definition, have a parent Opportunity so any formula fields that are like `Opportunity.xxx` will be available in the `OpportunityLineItem` "before insert" trigger. If your business logic ensures that all Opportunities must have Accounts, then formula fields like `Opportunity.Account.xxx` will also be available to the "before" trigger. Thus, no SOQL is required to access these fields.

`OpportunityId` is a required field in the schema.

However, OLIs inserted via DML or via the API may not have the required parent field (`OpportunityID`) set. In this use case, the formula field will resolve to null and your "before" trigger must accommodate. The record won't save because the required field check isn't run until the before trigger is completed.

---

Example 2 - `OpportunityLineItem` - cross object formula field to `PricebookEntry.Product2.xxx`

OLIs inserted from the standard UI must, by definition, have a PricebookEntry so any formula fields that are like `PricebookEntry.Product2.xxx` will be available in the `OpportunityLineItem` "before insert" trigger.

`PricebookEntryId` is a required field in the schema.

However, OLIs inserted via DML or via the API may not have the required parent field (`PricebookEntryID`) set. In this use case, the formula field will resolve to null and your "before insert" trigger must accommodate. Note the record won't save because the required field check is run after the before triggers execute..

---

Example 3 - `Opportunity` with cross object formula field to `Account.xxx`

The OOTB page layout has `AccountId` as a required field but you could have page layouts where this is not required. Furthermore, `AccountId` is not a required field in the schema for `Opportunity`.

Thus, as with the other examples, the "before" trigger may find the cross-object formula fields resolving to null depending on how whether the Opportunity record was CRUD with the required fields.

---

Lastly, since you can use DML or the API to update SObjects, the update might (errantly) null out required fields and your before update trigger's references to cross-object formula fields may resolve to null. A truly robust before update trigger that is doing logic against a parent object's values must allow for the use case where the lookup referenceId to the parent object is null or otherwise bogus. This is one of the reasons why trigger-based validations are recommended to be done in "after triggers" (once validation and required field checks have been completed)